# A confusion about list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am in face of a problem with regard to list comprehension,
and I am very confused about that.

For example,

```
def test(*args):
    list_1 = [i[0] for i in args]
    list_2 = [i[1] for i in args]
    print(list_1, list_2)
```

Here is a simple function, and we give an example list

```
list_test = [[18, 18, 17, 19]
             [14, 14, 15, 11]
             [14, 15, 10, 10]]

test(list_test)
```

Output:

```
[array([18, 18, 17, 19])] [array([14, 14, 15, 11])]
```

But if I just input:

```
[i[0] for i in list_test]
```

Output is different:

```
[18, 14, 14]
```

I don't know if I clearly explain my question...
Hope you can help me with that.
Very appreciated for your help!!!!

Comment: Your example input *absolutely does not* produce this output: `[array([18, 18, 17, 19])] [array([14, 14, 15, 11])]`. This looks like you are using `numpy`

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that you've defined your function with `def test(*args)`, that is, with variable number of arguments. So when you call `test(test_list)`, you've passed one argument, so `args == (test_list,)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you put *args with the star in front, it is sent as a tuple and it looks like this to the function test:

```
([[18, 18, 17, 19], [14, 14, 15, 11], [14, 15, 10, 10]],)
```

So, for i in args, is basically only elem in the tuple, a 2D

You mean to perform the list comprehension on the 2D directly.

so, you can either. remove the star, so that it considers as one singular argument.

or you can write.

```
for i in args[0]
```

this will, clear your confusion.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark my answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

for the given input:

```
list_test = [[18, 18, 17, 19]
         [14, 14, 15, 11]
         [14, 15, 10, 10]]
```

to reach the following output: [18,14,14] , [18,14,1]

you can do this:

```
print([i[0] for i in list_test], [i[1]] for in list_test)
```

if you are using numpy, use this:

```
 #list_test probably be a np.array
 #so you can do a transpose
 np.transpose(list_test)
```